# Why can't I graph r= 1 + 2cosθ by converting it into rectangular coordinates

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to graph the equation r = 1 + $2\cos \theta$ using its rectangular form.

I converted this equation to rectangular coordinates like this:

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 1 + 2 \cos\Biggl(\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{ (x^2+y^2)}}\right)\Biggl)$$

When I graph them I get:

[This graph for the cartesian form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJWSo.png)

[This graph for the polar form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcxKw.png)

The petal shape is not present in the cartesian form. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your graphing software is probably using just the positive square root.

Comment: Any idea how I can get the correct form so that it graphs correctly?

Comment: That depends on how the software works. You may want to graph several equations simultaneously, with $\pm$ on the square roots.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse cosine function is tricky.

Try parametric equations to graph the curve. $$x=(1+2\cos(\theta))\cos(\theta), y=(1+2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))$$

You should see the whole picture.